# Conditionally Display <th> tag in Razor

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

There are multiple rows of `<th>` & `<td>` tags in my code`(enclosed in @for loop)` which I want to display conditionally. One of such `<th>` tags looks like this:

```
@for (int j = 0; j < Model.Children.Count; j++)
{
 if (Model.Children[j].isCollapsible == true || Model.Children[j].IsCompany == true)
    {
<th class="..." style="width: 180px;">
    @Html.LabelForModel(Model.Children[j].Title)
    @if (Model.Children[j].isCollapsible == true && Model.Children[j].IsCompany == false)
                            {
                              // lines of code
                            }
</th>
 }
}
```

Although this works perfectly fine, but in order to make the code more compact, I want to replace the outer `if` in the above code snippet with a conditional `style=display:none` property for the `<th>` tag

I have tried `style="width: 180px; display: "@(Model.Children[j].isCollapsible == true || Model.Children[j].IsCompany == true)" ? none : table-cell"` but it shows an error:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the ternary with parentheses, with quotes around each value.

```
display:@(Model.Children[j].isCollapsible || Model.Children[j].IsCompany ? "none" : "table-cell")
```

Here is a stripped version which makes it easy to see where the quotes should be.

```
style="display:@(condition ? "" : "")"
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't work, I still see an error

Comment: There was an extra set of quotation marks around the value for display.  The quotes should be within the paraentheses around each value, not around the entire statement (since this statement is already enclosed in quotes).

Comment: yes, thanks, the error does go but the condition doesn't seem to have been applied when I see the output..I appended an !important with 'none' and 'table-cell'

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `"` after `display:`,and then add `""` outside `none` and `table-cell`.

```
<th class="..." style="width: 180px;display:@(Model.Children[j].isCollapsible==true || Model.Children[j].IsCompany==true ? "none" : "table-cell")">
     ...
</th>
```